# How to prevent users to close reward video ads till the video ad finishes

Tags: android, admob-rewardedvideoad

I use admob rewarded video and i want to disable the the close button until the ad finish or enable the close button after 10 second like ads on games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is neither possible nor promoted by admob, they will probably ban you if you try to achieve this anyway. You can use other video ad networks which do have similar functionality

Comment: you are welcome. Please accept my answer if i helped you

Comment: how to disable popup dialog that confirm the age when uses appmediation.com

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on what component you use for show video like,

If you are using activity then override onBackpress event and don't call the super method like below, It will restrict back press event from device button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

If you are using Dialog then set `setCancelable` `false` also `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` `false` like bellow

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```